# Select with parameters.add does not work

Tags: c#, postgresql, parameters

I really dont know what is happening here. It is a simple select with Parameters.Add and it does not work.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='@mail'";
command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@mail", userEmail));
```

If I change to the following command it works.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='" +userEmail + "'";
```

I tried with other columns of the table and the behaviour is the same. The email column is defined as TEXT NOT NULL.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure if it will fix it, but you shouldn't need to put the single quotes around the parameter in your SQL Statement: `command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email= @mail";` should be fine.

Comment: You really should declare your command text as a string literal, too.

Comment: As @Tim says, remove the single quotes.  By using single quotes you are actually making it NOT a parameter.  Single quotes specifically denote a string literal.  Think about how it works in C#.  You put double quotes around a String literal, right?  Do you put double quotes around a variable?  Of course not, because then it wouldn't be a variable.  This is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the single quote. I removed it and the code worked.